# How to shim OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a WPF ViewModel, that has a command which opens a File dialog like this:

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Now I would like to unit test that command. ShowDialog is a method inherited from the CommonDialog, so I assumed I can shim it like this:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimCommonDialog.AllInstances.ShowDialog = () => true;
```

but I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Delegate `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.FakesDelegates.Func<Microsoft.Win32.CommonDialog,bool?>` does not take 0 arguments

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but doesn't a dialog return a DialogResult, as opposed to a bool? Perhaps by specifying a bool you are causing a different delegate to be used that expects a parameter to be passed in.

Comment: ShowDialog returns nullable bool i.e. "bool?"

Comment: @CodeontheCommode: You are thinking of Form.ShowDialog. OpenFileDialog returns a nullable bool as filip has said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code would achieve what you need.

**System Under Test (SUT)**

```
public class Sut
{
    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        return result.Value;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test (using MS Fakes)**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Win32.Fakes;
using WpfApplication1;

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        using (var context = ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            Nullable<bool> b2 = true;
            ShimCommonDialog.AllInstances.ShowDialog = (x) => b2;

            var sut = new Sut();

            var r = sut.SomeMethod();

            Assert.IsTrue(r);
        }
    }
```

Note that you need to have the **PresentationFramework.4.0.0.0.Fakes** assembly as well as the correct additional Fakes assemblies in your test.

Comment: ok, so I was missing this x - why it's required there if OpenDialog takes no arguments?

Comment: It does take an argument, it takes an instance of the dialog it opens. It may be an extension method, or have an optional parameter.