# shim a sealed class singleton method and with MS Fakes

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

i have a sealed class singleton Foo and its method:

```
    public string GetFolderPath(FooFolder folder)
    {
        IBoo boo = this.GetBoo();
        return boo.GetFolderPath(folder);
    }
```

and want to write a test for a method called FindFile using the GetFolderPath method like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void FindFile()
    {   
        string expectedPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TestPath");
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            Fakes.ShimFoo.AllInstances.GetFolderPathFolder
                = () => { return "C:\\...\\Temp"; };

        }
        string actualPath = WorkflowHelper.FindFile("TestPath");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedPath, actualPath);
    }
```

the problem is that i'm getting the following compilation error:

Delegate does not take 0 arguments

In an similar Question [How to shim OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586386/how-to-shim-openfiledialog-showdialog-method) the problem is solved like this :

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    using (var context = ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        Nullable<bool> b2 = true;
        ShimCommonDialog.AllInstances.ShowDialog = (x) => b2;

        var sut = new Sut();

        var r = sut.SomeMethod();

        Assert.IsTrue(r);
    }
}
```

So i tried the same... according to the fact that GetFolderPath is a method with 1 Parameter...

next problem is that i'm getting the following compilation error:

Delegate does not take 1 arguments

So my question is:

Is it possible to shim a sealed class and particulary a singleton? And if so, what´s my mistake?

thank you in anticipation

Comment: What did you exactly try the second time?

Comment: So you found the solution.

Comment: One time i tried with 0 Argument then i found this similar question and tired with 1 Argument...  so i had compilation error: does not take 1 Argument... but that was my false. According to the fact that GetFolderPath is a method with one parameter, the Lambda Expression takes 2 arguments

Comment: So no compilation error anymore...sorry for that... but there is another problem...
Compilation works but the GetFolderPath method does not return the shimed result.
Im realy sorry for that... im just new in developing...
but that leads to my actual question...thank you for your fast reply Alireza

Comment: why GetFolderPath does not return the shimmed result? it is very simple. The existing method will be replaced by the new definition. Tell me the problem and I will help you

Comment: I want to test a method called FindFile. This method calls another method(GetFolderPath) of a singleton named Foo for example like this: Foo.Instance.GetFolderPath(folder). So i want to shim Foo`s method GetFolderPath to return a fixed result and tried it like the code above. Compilation works but the Foo.Instance.GetFolderPath(folder) method doesn`t return my shimed result:

Comment: Is your singleton instance created outside the Shim context?

Comment: Well can´t tell you. But u think i cant fake the singleton method if the singleton already exists?? i´ll try that

Comment: I'm also testing this myself

Comment: I was wrong. I works for the singleton too

Comment: although the singleton is already created??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that all shims assigned in the lifetime of `ShimsContext` will be destroyed after the `ShimsContext` is disposed.

In your sample, you are invoking `WorkflowHelper.FindFile` outside the using block that binds the lifetime of your `ShimsContext`, so the shimmed definition for `Foo.GetFolderPath` is no longer effective and the call to FindFile will use the original method definition.

Just move your method call inside the `using` block and it will work:

```
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        Fakes.ShimFoo.AllInstances.GetFolderPathFolder = ...; // your lambda expression

        string actualPath = WorkflowHelper.FindFile("TestPath");
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedPath, actualPath);
```

Comment: Well such stupid for my part... and that easy... thanks a thousand times :D

Comment: I'm sorry to overlook such a simple thing :)